# Performance of python when passing big data as function parameter

Tags: python, performance

Suppose I have two **Python** functions, **Function 1** and **Function 2**.

**Function 1** will call **Function 2** and the parameter is a big data (*e.g.*, a dictionary with 100 thousand elements).

I am wondering if there is any performance differences between calling **Function 2** in **Function 1**, which means I need to pass the big data parameter, and implementing **Function 2** in **Function 1** directly, which means I don't need to pass the big data parameter.

Thanks.

PS: I think the key question is how **Python** pass the parameter, by value, or by reference (pointer)?

Edit: It seems that this is a confused problem. [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) is a good answer.

Comment: So what were the results when you tried both options and timed them, again? :)

Comment: Python is all pass by reference, so you should be fine :-)

Comment: @LevLevitsky Testing is fine but quite often a precise answer on inner workings is preferable

Comment: @LevLevitsky This question come to my mind when I try to implement Function 2. I will implement both ways and see if there is any difference. thx

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Python passes references-to-objects by value. The terminology is controversial and ugly, but there should be no real performance difference.

Check out [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) for all the details you could ever want (hopefully).

Comment: (and all the details you hoped you never need to know)

Answer (score 7):

The terminology of how python "passes" is a vicious debate I don't want to go into. But what is actually passed on the stack is a reference.  So there is not a large memory cost with either of your options.